# Include user locale to the Keycloak ID token

Tags: javascript, locale, keycloak

I would like Keycloak (1.4.0) to include the users' chosen locale to the ID token.

I have come as far as creating a user attribute mapper, which was supposed to map the locale attribute to the token, but it does not work.

**Does anybody know how to do this?**

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have learnt what I know abput Keycloak Locales from this class: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.keycloak/keycloak-forms-common-freemarker/1.2.0.Final/org/keycloak/freemarker/LocaleHelper.java#LocaleHelper.0LOGGER

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem on my own. I ended up using loadUserProfile() function from Keycloak JS adapter. It loads all the user attributes (including locale) into keycloak.profile object, so I didn't have to configure any mappers.

Comment: Good that it's working now. I used custom attributes, apparently profile attributes are handled differently :)

Comment: probably it makes internally a call to userinfo profile. With id_token you can skip the additional call. Still better to use what is simpler for you

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you already have something like this:

1. Open the admin console of your realm.
2. Go to Clients and select your client
3. This only works for Settings > Access Type confidential or public (not bearer-only)
4. Go to Mappers
5. Create a mapping from your attribute to json
6. Check "Add to ID token"

To access the mapped claim you use something like this:

```
final Principal userPrincipal = httpRequest.getUserPrincipal();

if (userPrincipal instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {

    KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> kp = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) userPrincipal;
    IDToken token = kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken();

    Map<String, Object> otherClaims = token.getOtherClaims();

    if (otherClaims.containsKey("YOUR_CLAIM_KEY")) {
        yourClaim = String.valueOf(otherClaims.get("YOUR_CLAIM_KEY"));
    }
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException(...);
}
```

Hope this helps and fits your use case. I used this for a custom attribute I added with a custom theme.

Comment: I already tried this, but the problem is that locale is not accesible in that way, so i had to work with user profile.

Comment: I did like you suggested, but I only get a null IDToken. Adding the data to the access token works, though, I can then get it from there. This is with spring-security 4.0 and keycloak 1.7

Comment: That's strange. Even without custom variables you should get the standard IdToken and not null.