# Setting keycloak user locale using keycloak java library

Tags: java, keycloak

[image: ?]

Does anybody know how can I set locale field while creating new user using keycloak admin client (java library). I am using keycloak 3.2.0.FINAL version.

And is this possible to set this for all existing users also using admin-client?

Comment: The locale is included in the user representation as an attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32955072/1199132 There's a `Map` containing the attributes: http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/2.5/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation You just need to use the API to create it.

Comment: Thanks Xtreme Biker.. since it was a comment, i couldn't accept your answer.

Answer (score 15):

Got the answer-
userRepresentation.singleAttribute("locale", "en");