# Set and update Keycloak/OpenId-Connect Claims in Client application

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, spring-security, keycloak

I'd like to know if and how it is possible to **set and update** **Keycloak** (OpenID-Connect) **AccessToken** or **IdToken attributes** (so called Claims) **by a client web application**, after successful authentication.

The use case is to add specific user-attributes (e.g. number of pets, hair color, favorite car, etc.) to the Access- or Id-Token, while the user is logged in to our web application based on a Vue.js Frontend and a SpringBoot Backend, mainly exposing REST Services to the Frontend.
A second web-application, also using the Keycloak Token for user authentication/authorization (Single-Sign-On feature) should be able to read the user-attributes added by the first web-application to the Token.

Even I'm afraid that adding and changing of Token payload is not allowed by architectural design of OpenId-Connect, I nevertheless hope it will be possible anyhow.

Token-attributes are implemented as 'Claims' in OpenId-Connect. And Keycloak supports 'Claim' mappings during the authentication process (set by static mappings on Keycloak server as well as by code that runs on the Keycloak server).

The appropriate methods to set and get Claim key-value pairs are mentioned by the following articles:

[How to create a Script Mapper in Keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518298/how-to-create-a-script-mapper-in-keycloak):

`token.getOtherClaims().put("myClaimName", "claim value");`

[Include user locale to the Keycloak ID token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696439/include-user-locale-to-the-keycloak-id-token):

```
Map<String, Object> otherClaims = token.getOtherClaims();
if (otherClaims.containsKey("myClaimName")) {
  String claimValue = String.valueOf(otherClaims.get("myClaimName"));
}
```

For the case changing of Token payload by Keycloak clients is not allowed by architectural design, I appreciate any suggestion on best practices to hand over dynamically added user-attributes from one webapp to another webapp, having the same Keycloak Access- and/or Id-Token in common.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing of token payload by user application is not allowed/possible by architectural design. App doesn't own private key, which is required to create proper token signature, when you change payload.

Comment: Thanks Jan! 
Adding Payload of Token by calling the method token.getOtherClaims().put("myClaimName", "claim value");
was possible in client application (even without knowing/applying the private key), but the added claim was not propagated to other clients under the same Keycloak realm.

Comment: @MajestixFinger yes you "can add" custom claim, but you won't be able to generate correct signature, so other app will reject this invalid token with your custom claim, but invalid signature. So what is the point of adding claim, when it will be rejected?

Comment: The behaviour I observed was, that the other clients don't reject changed token as invalid, rather the token change seems not to be propagated to other clients. 
I suppose that there is only a local copy of the token (generated by Spring Security framework) under the client where the token change resp. claim adding is done.
Thus I think this is the reason that added token claim will not be visible by other clients.